# Finding World file info?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, world-file

I'm very new to GIS.

How do I find the following info?

1. x resolution    <--the number of real world units per pixel in the X direction
2. amount of translation  <-- usually 0 or a very small number
3. amount of rotation   <-- usually 0 or a very small number
4. negative of the y resolution  <-- the negative of the number of real world units per pixel in the Y direction
5. xMin coordinate (upper left)
6. yMax coordinate (upper left)

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163978/what-file-format-is-this-can-i-get-a-bounding-box-out-of-it/164013#164013

Comment: Haven't you answered you own question. You write the appropriate size numbers into a text file and save it as tfw? You could use just about any programming language under the sun to do this more generically.

Comment: pardon me for being unclear. I would like to know how to find those 6 things so I can write them down. where can I find them?

Comment: You mean a [World File](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file) ?

Comment: yes that is what I mean